# Do "die for something" & "kill for something" have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

[die for something](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/die-for-something): To have a very strong desire for something : I'm dying for a drink/ Kids die for Sugar Glops

[kill for something](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/kill-for-something?s=t): To be willing to go to great extremes to get something : I'd kill for a beer now

So, Do "**I'd kill for a beer now**" & "**I'd die for a beer now**" have the same meaning?

Comment: I think you figured it out yourself.

Comment: I think that we can say something about a difference (or lack of difference) in tone/nuance between these two expressions without going to far into the realm of pure opinion, so I don't think this should be closed. Just because the dictionary says things have the same meaning doesn't mean they are used the same way colloquially.

Comment: The difference may be more obvious if we change the tense: *I'm killing for a beer now* vs. *I'm dying for a beer now*.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly, no. The meanings differ.

In *very* informal speech you are almost always going to be understood to mean the same thing in either case.

But there are cases in which you might want to take care.

Still in English (if not universally) there are simple rules that can help you decide when you should be careful.

When you

1. use a figure of speech--an expression

   **and**
2. your topic relates to one of the content words in your intended figure of speech

you need to consider what your listeners will understand.

You **do** risk *not being understood at all* or *being understood to have said something much different than you meant*.

For instance, you might hope to be a martyr for some cause.  However you should not use either of these expressions in this context. They involve *killing* and *dying* so your listeners could easily become confused.

You **can't** reasonably say anything like the following:

> I would die to be a martyr for [*anything that you say here is wrong*].
>
> I and my gang would kill to have the contract on his life.

You **could** say:

> After three years abroad I would kill for a decent milkshake.
>
> I am dying to get my hands on a new car.  The daily walk to the office is killing me.

*Why specifically?*

1. To choose to die for something *is* to be a martyr.  The statement is illogical.
2. A contract for someone's life is a promise of money in exchange for a killing. Here the statement *isn't* illogical.

It is possible that you could become a paid killer if you had
    already killed someone. But you can't say it this way. You might sound as if you were making a joke--or maybe what you mean is unclear.

It's confusing for anyone listening. So [assuming it is what you mean] it would be best to say

> We would be willing to murder someone to get that contract.

Those are extreme examples but when your meaning is even *potentially related*  you can have the same problem.

You can say *I would kill for a beer now* but you can't say *I would kill for a friend* if you mean *I would like to have a friend*.

Likewise *I'd die for a beer now* is perfect English.  But in a hostage crisis don't say *I'd die for a friend now*.

Comment: +1 -- I think *I and my gang would kill to have the contract on his life* is possible, though, something like "We would kill other gangs to get the contract".

Comment: It’s possible but never clear.